# Jquery validation plugin not validate dynamic select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, cakephp

Hello I'm having trouble with validation on dynamic select box. Jquery validation not validate the rest of dynamic select box instead the existing one.
Noted that I'm using CakePHP 2.5, Bootstrap 3 , and Jquery validation.

Below is my code.

HTML

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Redemption',array('type'=>'file','id'=>'redeemForm')); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="row"  id="proRow_0">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Product Purchased</label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Product.0.type_id',array('class'=>'form-control product-select','id'=>'product_0','label'=>false,'empty'=>array(''=>'Choose Product'),'div'=>false));?>
                </div>                      
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="moreProduct"></div>
    <a id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
   <a id="remove"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Remove</a>
```

Javascript

```
    $('#add').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        rmBtn.show();

        var productRow = $('#moreProduct');

        $.get('<?php echo $this->webroot;?>/redemptions/getProductType.json', function(data) {

            var proRow = 'proRow_'+index;
            var modelID = 'model_'+index;
            var quantityID = 'quantity_'+index;
            var newPRow = '<div class="row moreProduct" id="'+proRow+'">';

            newPRow += '<div class="col-md-4 product-type-field">';
            newPRow += '<select class="form-control product-select" name="data[Product]['+index+'][type_id]" id="product_'+index+'">';
            newPRow += '<option>Choose Product</option>';
            $.each(data,function(key, val) {
                newPRow += "<option value=\""+key+"\">"+val+"</option>";
            });

            newPRow += '</select></div><div class="col-md-4 product-model-field" id="'+modelID+'"></div><div class="col-md-4 product-quantity-field" id="'+quantityID+'"></div>';
            productRow.append(newPRow);

            var productTfield = $('.product-type-field');
            var productMfield = $('.product-model-field');
            var productQfield = $('.product-quantity-field');

            //assign new style
            $('#moreProduct').css({'margin-top': '-10px'});
            productTfield.css({'margin-top': '10px'});
            productMfield.css({'margin-top': '10px'});
            productQfield.css({'margin-top': '10px'});


            $('select[name*="type_id"]').each(function() {
                $(this).on('change', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var proID = $(this).val();
                    var modelID = $(this).attr('id').substring(8);
                    var quantityID = $(this).attr('id').substring(8);
                    var modelID = $('#'+proRow).find($('#model_'+modelID)).attr('id');
                    var quantityID = $('#'+proRow).find($('#quantity_'+quantityID)).attr('id');


                    if (modelID) {
                        var productMfield = $('div[id^="'+modelID+'"]');
                        var productQfield =  $('div[id^="'+quantityID+'"]');

                        $.post("<?php echo $this->webroot;?>/redemptions/getProductModel.json",{proID : proID}).done(function(data){
                            productMfield.html("");

                            var modelVal = modelID.substring(6);
                            var quantityVal = quantityID.substring(9);
                            var modelSelect = '<select class="form-control model-select" name="data[Product]['+modelVal+'][model_id]">';

                            $.each(data,function(key, val) {
                                modelSelect += "<option value=\""+val.Product.id+"\">"+val.Product.product_model+"</option>";
                            });

                            modelSelect += '</select>';
                            productMfield.append(modelSelect);

                            productQfield.html();

                            var newQuantity = '<input type="text" class="form-control quantity" placeholder="Quantity" id="qval_'+quantityVal+'"name="data[Product]['+modelVal+'][quantity]">';

                            productQfield.append(newQuantity);

                            quantityID = $('#'+proRow).find($('#qval_'+quantityVal)).attr('id');
                            quantityID = $('#'+quantityID);
                            qListener(quantityID);

                        });
                    }else{
                        existFieldListener();
                    };
                });
            });
        });
        index++;
    });


function formValidation(){
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                // console.log(element.type);
                // console.log(this.findByName(element.name));
                if (element.type == 'radio') {
                    this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                } else if(element.type == 'select-one'){
                    console.log('yes');
                    console.log(errorClass);
                    console.log($('select-one'));
                    $('select-one').each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                    });
                    // $(element).closest('.product-type-field').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                }else if(element.name == 'data[Redemption][retailer_id]'){
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.fa').remove();
                }else {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.fa').remove();
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                if (element.type === "radio") {
                    this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                } else {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.fa').remove();
                }
            }
        });

        $.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
            return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
        }); 


        $('#redeemForm').validate({
            debug:true, 
            ignore: '*:not([name])',
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            },
            accept: function(value, element, param) {
                return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
            },
            rules: {
                "data[Redemption][date_purchased]":{
                    required:true,
                },
                "data[Redemption][invoice_no]":{
                    required:true,
                },
                "data[Customer][customer_name]":{
                    required:true,
                },
                "data[Product][0][type_id]":{
                    required:true,
                },

                "data[Customer][primary_address]":{
                    required:true,
                },
                "data[Customer][nric_no]":{
                    required:true,
                    accept:"[a-zA-Z0-9]+",
                }, 
                "data[Redemption][invoice]":{
                    required:true,
                },
                "data[Customer][customer_email]":{
                    required:true,
                    email:true,
                },
                "data[Customer][contact_no]":{
                    required:true,
                    number: true
                },
                "data[Customer][city]":{
                    required :true,
                    accept: "[a-zA-Z]+",
                },
                "data[Customer][postal_code]":{
                    required :true,
                    accept: "[0-9]+",
                },
                "data[Customer][state]":{
                    required :true,
                },
            },
            messages:{
                "data[Customer][customer_email]":{
                    email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
                },
                "data[Customer][contact_no]":{
                    number: "Your contact must be in the format of 03xxxxxx/019xxxxxx"
                },
                "data[Customer][city]":{
                    accept:"Accept letter only"
                },
                "data[Customer][postal_code]":{
                    accept:"Accept number only"
                }, 
                "data[Customer][nric_no]":{
                    accept:"NRIC no. must be in in the format of 123456xxxxxx without '-'"
                }
            },
            setDefaults: {
                ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else if (element.is('#retailers')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.siblings(".chzn-container"));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
        });
    $('#redeemForm').on('submit', function() {
        $(this).validate();
        // $('input').each(function () {
        //  $(this).rules('add', {
        //      required: true,
        //  });
        // });
        $('select[name*="type_id"]').each(function() {
            // console.log($(this));
            $(this).rules('add',{
                required:true,
            });
        });
    });


}
```

Really appreciate your help and time. Thanks

Comment: Dynamically created content is not in the DOM, you have to tell the new created elements how the have to react by calling the validation function again.

Comment: as you can see at the code,I already add the rules once again when the form on submit.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't attach anything to the `submit` event, instead use the `submitHandler` option of the `$.validate` call:

```
$('#redeemForm').validate({
  submitHandler:function(){
    //This is called when the form successfully submits with no validation errors
  }
});
```

Second, you need to attach the validation to the select right after you append it to the row.  So, in your `$.get` handler, after you append the row, add your validation:

```
 //in your $.get handler
 productRow.append(newPRow);

 $('#product_'+index).rules('add',{
    required: true
 });

 var productTfield = $('.product-type-field');

 //...and it continues after here
```